# Plotting a numpy array on matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0],[1],[2]], np.int32)
b=np.array([[3],[4],[5]], np.int32)

plt.plot(a, color = 'red', label = 'Historical data')
plt.plot(b, color = 'blue', label='Predicted data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

That gives me a graph of 2 lines each starting from `x-axis = 0`.

How can I concatenate `'a'` and `'b'` and plot the graph such that `'b'` continues on the `x-axis` where `'a'` ended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `x` array and then increase its value in the next plot so it will get appended to the previous plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0],[1],[2]], np.int32)
b=np.array([[3],[4],[5]], np.int32)
x = np.arange(a.shape[0])

plt.plot(x, a, color = 'red', label = 'Historical data')
plt.plot(x+a.shape[0], b, color = 'blue', label='Predicted data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Follow up question:
What if the numpy arrays are:
a=np.array([[0],[1],[2]], np.int32)
b=np.array([[2],[3],[4],[5]], np.int32)
?

I get this error:
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3,) and (4, 1)

How can i get around this?

Comment: Since the shape of `a` and `b` are different here you'll have to make two different `x` variable `x1 = np.arange(a.shape[0])` and `x2 = np.arange(a.shape[0], a.shape[0]+b.shape[0])`. `x1` can be used with a and `x2` can be used with `b`